# AWS upload file to S3 Access Denied with user who has full s3 access - React Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm trying to use the react-native-s3-upload package to upload files to an S3 bucket in my React Native App. This only works if I set "Block public access" to 'off' in S3. Otherwise I get `<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>`. The access key and secret key provided with put requests are for an IAM user that belongs to a group with AmazonS3FullAccess. I also have this policy attached to the bucket:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policyxxxxxxx",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmtxxxxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:user/<user name>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried all sorts of solutions but nothing seems to work. If I replace the secret key and access keys with dummy text then it returns `<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>` so  it's definitely signing me in with the keys but seems to be ignoring the permissions.

Comment: The bucket policy shown doesn't allow *any* object access. An object resource would be `arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*`

Comment: changed it to arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*  - still getting access denied

Comment: You haven't shown any code so we're guessing a little here but are you setting an ACL of `public-read` or similar when you upload the object? You won't be able to make an object public if you have enabled Block Public Access. You should probably use `bucket-owner-full-control`.

Comment: I set it to bucket-owner-full-control and it now works - Raul's answer also works too. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IAM user has AmazonS3FullAccess policy, it should connect to bucket just fine.

I think that the problem is that default object acl is public,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-s3-upload

*acl - The Access Control List of this object. Defaults to public-read*

You need to set it to **private**.